# How to retrieve a value from html form and use that value inside the sql query in python in flask framework

Tags: python, mysql, flask, fetch, using

Basically from the dropdown menu in my html form , I select the value and using that value I try to fetch the Mysql database in my python flask program. I get syntax error stating my sql is invalid : ""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1") ".

Code in python flask:

```
@app.route("/test1",methods=["GET","POST"])
def test1():
      var1 = request.form['Item_1']
      cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
      res_val = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = {}".format(var1))
      resolve1 = cur.fetchall()
      return render_template("test1.html",resolve1=resolve1)
```

code in html form:

```
<form name="Item_1" action="{{ url_for('test1')}}" method="POST">
                <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
                  <select name="Item_1" id="Item_1">
                    {% for comment1 in comments1 %}
                     <option value={{comment1.id}}>{{comment1[0]}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can import the "request" from flask and use it when the request method is POST

following code would help ->

```py
from flask import request
'''
rest of your code
'''
@app.route("/test1",methods=["GET","POST"])
def test1():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_value = request.form.get('Item_1')
        # Or you could use request.form['Item_1'] because request.form is a dictionary
```

Then simply use the form_value while rendering the template or anything.

Also, 'Item_1' is the name that you used in the HTML form under the name attribute.
It would be better if you change the name for the form tag and for the list item tag (the one used in the select tag)

---

This edit to your command might help :
res_val = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = {var1}".format(var1=var1))

Comment: i made the required changes to the sql query but still get the error : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")